# IFS variable and filenames with spaces and newlines

Tags: find, filenames

(Using Bash 4.4 and 5.0)

I am dealing with the issue of filenames that contain spaces, newlines and backslashes. I often read the suggestion to use code like this:

```
oldIFS=$IFS 
IFS= 

while read -rd '' LINE ; do
     ...
```

or

```
while IFS= read -rd '' LINE ; do
   ...
```

However, I find the use of the IFS variable in this context isn't necessary. Apparently so:

I have a directory with these files:

```
$ ls -a1
.
..
he\llo
hello?w o r l d
listing
```

The ? in the fourth one stands for a newline. The file **listing** is the script that produces the output further down below:

```
$ cat listing
#!/bin/bash

#IFS=
i=0

while read -rd '' FILE; do
    (( i++ ))
    echo -n $i"  "
    ls -ld "$FILE"
done
```

Now using **find -print0 | ./listing** gives me this output"

```
$ find -print0 | ./listing
1  drwxr-xr-x 2 pi pi 4096 Feb 15 16:34 .
2  -rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 6 Feb 15 06:12 ./hello?w o r l d
3  -rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 6 Feb 15 05:30 ./he\llo
4  -rwxr--r-- 1 pi pi 99 Feb 15 16:34 ./listing
```

Which is totally okay. The result is the same if I remove the # in front of IFS in the script **listing**.

So, modifying IFS doesn't appear to be necessary here.

Am I missing an angle? Under what circumstances would the IFS= be required here?

Comment: I don't think setting `IFS=` (to null?) is the same as `unset IFS`.

Comment: I also checked what happens when I unset IFS - by replacing the line 'IFS=' with 'unset IFS'. No difference. Apparently IFS is not involved in the operation or its content doesn't matter.

Comment: `read` will strip flanking `$IFS` whitespace off from the read word (with the default value of `$IFS`).  Related: [Understanding "IFS= read -r line"](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/209123)